# tvOS blur with UIVisualEffectView

Tags: swift, tvos, uivisualeffectview

When I add a `UIVisualEffectView` with a blur effect to a ViewController that gets pushed onto the navigation stack the blurred view is grey while the ViewController appears and then turns to its proper blurring effect. 
(See the screenshots) The same happens to the buttons.

What do I have to do to get this working and prevent this ugly transition?

The ViewController during the transition:
 [image: transition]

The ViewController when the transition is completed:
[image: transition complete]

Comment: were you able to solve it?